# The program needs to print 'you pressed A' only when a is pressed. but when i check with the IF statemend, it passes it and goes to the else

Tags: json

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def show(key):
    key = str(key)
    if key == 'a':
        print('you pressed a')
    else:
        print('not working')
# Collect all event until released
with Listener(on_press = show) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It should go in the if statment. insted it passes it and goes to the else. why?

Comment: Please tag your question properly. This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked, what are you getting in `key` variable? print the value of `key` in the console furthermore you can also check the type of value receiving in the `key variable` and convert it accordingly while comparing it in the `if` section